# Migration of Applications to newer .NET Framwork version necessary or just update runtime?

Tags: .net, .net-core

Imagine you have an old .NET Framework Application, built with v4.6.1 (Target Version 4.6.1).

The runtime version 4.6.1 is out of support:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework

Is it necessary to migrate the application to a supported version (e.g. 4.6.2 or higher), when there are no errors after testing the unmodified application on a 4.6.2 runtime?

Or is it ok to just update the runtime on the server?

The same goes for example an .NetCore 3.1 application. This runtime will be unsupported at the end of 2022. Do I have to migrate the app or just update the runtime?

Comment: This can't be answered. .NET Core is a completely different runtime. Whether you migrate to a more modern version of .NET Framework or .NET Core depends on *your application* and its requirements. Is it a desktop or web app? WinForms or WPF? WebForms, MVC or Web API? WebForms was never migrated to .NET Core and never will. Do you want your application to be cross-platform or run in containers?

Comment: `the runtime on the server` what server and what version? Most likely the application is *already* running on .NET Framework 4.6.2 simply because all recent Server versions come with it or a newer version. 4.6.1 went out of support because the Windows versions that came with it also went out of support. .NET Framework 4.x versions are binary replacements and installing a new runtime replaces the older one. A Windows Update may have upgraded the runtime already

Comment: "Applications targeting a .NET Framework version that is no longer supported will not need to retarget or recompile to a newer version as they can be run on a later .NET Framework version." https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1/

Comment: But .NET Core 3.1 app must be recompiled to run on .NET 5, 6, 7 etc

Comment: @Martheen, did you find any reference for "But .NET Core 3.1 app must be recompiled to run on .NET 5, 6, 7"?

Comment: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2021/Jun/15/Running-NET-Core-Apps-on-a-Framework-other-than-Compiled-Version